# SDL2 Access violation multiple windows

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I am developing SDL2 application which needs to have multiple windows on multiple monitors. And I am getting access violation when drawing string with SDL_ttf library. I should also mention that Application is opening windows in separate threads and is working ok if there is no SDL_ttf used. 
I get this for exception when using SDL_ttf:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0F2BC191 (SDL2.dll) in SDLMultipleWindows.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0100000C.
```

And access violation is happening in this function:

```
bool loadFromRenderedText( std::string textureText, SDL_Color textColor )
{
    SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid( gFont, textureText.c_str(), textColor );
    SDL_Texture * mTexture = NULL;
    int w, h;
    if( textSurface != NULL )
    {
        mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, textSurface );
        w = textSurface->w;
        h = textSurface->h;
        SDL_FreeSurface( textSurface );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Unable to render text surface! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError() );
    }

    SDL_Rect renderQuad = { 250, 300, w, h };
    int result = SDL_RenderCopyEx( renderer, mTexture, NULL, &renderQuad, 0.0, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE );
    OutputDebugString(SDL_GetError());
    return true;
}
```

Exception happens on SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, textSurface);

This is stack trace from Visual studio:

```
SDL2.dll!SDL_malloc_REAL(unsigned int bytes) Line 4206  C
SDL2.dll!SDL_calloc_REAL(unsigned int n_elements, unsigned int elem_size) Line 4406 C
SDL2.dll!SDL_CreateRGBSurface_REAL(unsigned int flags, int width, int height, int depth, unsigned int Rmask, unsigned int Gmask, unsigned int Bmask, unsigned int Amask) Line 53    C
SDL2.dll!SDL_ConvertSurface_REAL(SDL_Surface * surface, const SDL_PixelFormat * format, unsigned int flags) Line 840    C
SDL2.dll!SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface_REAL(SDL_Renderer * renderer, SDL_Surface * surface) Line 536 C
SDL2.dll!SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(SDL_Renderer * a, SDL_Surface * b) Line 342   C
SDLMultipleWindows.exe! loadFromRenderedText(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > textureText, SDL_Color textColor) Line 162    C++
```

Am I doing something wrong or SDL_ttf or SDL2 cannot work on multiple threads?

Is there another way to draw string in SDL2?

Thanks!

Edit:

Adding part of existing code:

```
ClientWindows::ClientWindows(void)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    TTF_Init();
}
```

Tread function:
    void ClientWindows::WindowThread(int i)
    {
        AppWindow* rWindow = new AppWindow(i * 1024, 0);
        Windows.push_back(rWindow);
        rWindow->InitScreen();
    }

Start graphics function:

```
void ClientWindows::StartGraphics(int number)
{
    for(int i= 0; i<number; i++)
    {
        std::thread* wTread = new std::thread(&ClientWindows::WindowThread,this , i);
        Threads.push_back(wTread);
    }
.
.
.
```

Client window Constructor:

```
AppWindow::AppWindow(int x, int y)
{
    quit = false;
    SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024;
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 768;
    imagePositionX = 50;
    imagePositionY = 50;
    speed_x = 10;
    speed_y = 10;
    moveX = 10;
    moveY = 10;
    std::ostringstream convert;
    convert << "Graphics";
    convert << x;
    string name = convert.str();

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(name.c_str(), x,
    y, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (window == nullptr){
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    opengl3_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    SDL_assert(opengl3_context);
    mt.lock();
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (renderer == nullptr){
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    mt.unlock();
    background = nullptr,image = nullptr;
    background = SDLLoadImage("../res/Image1024x768.png");
    image = SDLLoadImage("../res/Image1024Classic.png");
    animeImage = SDLLoadImage("../res/32_80x80.png");
    gFont = TTF_OpenFont("../res/sample.ttf", 28);
}
```

Client window startGraphics function:

```
void AppWindow::InitScreen(void)
{
    Clear();
    Render();
    Present();

    //Init fps
    countedFrames = 0;
    fpsTimer.start();

    //For tracking if we want to quit
    Uint32 frameRate = 0;
    while (!quit)
    {
        if (fpsTimer.getTicks() > frameRate + 15)
        {
            frameRate = fpsTimer.getTicks();
            Clear();
            Render();
            Present();
        }
        SDL_Delay(5);
    }
}
```

Function in question:

```
bool AppWindow::loadFromRenderedText(std::string textureText, SDL_Color textColor)
{
    SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid( gFont, textureText.c_str(), textColor );
    SDL_Texture * mTexture = NULL;
    int w, h;
    if( textSurface != NULL )
    {
        mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, textSurface );
        w = textSurface->w;
        h = textSurface->h;
        SDL_FreeSurface( textSurface );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Unable to render text surface! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError() );
    }

    SDL_Rect renderQuad = { 250, 300, w, h };
    int result = SDL_RenderCopyEx( renderer, mTexture, NULL, &renderQuad, 0.0, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE );
    OutputDebugString(SDL_GetError());
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SDL2 functions from other threads than the one in which the rendering context was created, SDL2 guarantees no thread safety for drawing functions.

If I recall correctly, the only thread safe part of SDL2 is pushing custom events to the event queue.

So I'm guessing the **AccessViolation** occurs because you're trying to use the renderering context from another thread than from on the one which it was created on.

Comment: Ok, but I am creating new instance of renderer and window in every thread. Doesn't that make it a part of that thread?

Comment: Are you performing the CreateSurfaceFromTexture in the same thread as the one you created the renderer in?

Comment: Yes. I create 10 threads and in every of them I initialize new renderer and window. Every renderer gets its own memory address but maybe they share some static memory in between.

Comment: I know you create them in different threads, I'm asking if the thread from where you perform an action on the renderer is the same thread that created that renderer.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I moved this function into class that I pass to the thread and this class is only accessed from that thread.

Comment: Hmm, I would employ the use of gdb or similar(a debugger at least), its hard to tell what causes the problem as it is :p